# How to get the link dynamicallY?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one problem.I have some directories which contain text files.I have read the full path of the directory and got the last one which contain the text file.Now I have dynamically ctreated the link to this directories and displayed them on the page.Now my problem is how to fetch the data from the text file contained inside the folder?
As the buttonlink which I have created is dynamic I cannot handle the event on it..
So can anybody help me sort out this problem?

Thanking Each 1 of you,

Swapnil

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the `LinkButton` controls are created in your code-behind. Then you can set up a click event handler like this in your code-behind file:

```
public LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = sender As LinkButton;
    // button is now the clicked LinkButton; get whatever you need from it
}
```

When you create the `LinkButton` controls, attach the event handler to them:

```
LinkButton newButton = new LinkButton();
newButton.Click += LinkButton_Click;
```

Comment: Are you sure that he asked how to wire up his button? :)

Comment: @Henrik - The follwing phrase on in the question led me to believe that: *"As the buttonlink which I have created is dynamic I cannot handle the event on it.. So can anybody help me sort out this problem?"*. I may be wrong though... But as you mention in your answer; the question is not entirely clear.